# How can I win the Seacrest Tour event in Need For Speed: Hot Pursuit?

Tags: need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2010

How can I win the Seacrest Tour event, or at least get bronze?

I've tried this event many times, the best I've managed is 4th. I'd particularly like help on these specific points:

- Which car should I use? The Bugatti Veyron looks the best option from the stats, but should I try something else?
- How can I avoid crashing? I often fail to finish because I wreck my car.
- Should I be taking shortcuts? If so, which ones?
- In the Freeway sections, should I drive on the correct side of the road or try to earn boost by driving into oncoming traffic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was eventually able to finish 2nd using the following tactics:

- drive whichever car you find easiest to control - in my case the McLaren
- don't take any shortcuts
- drive on the correct side of the road on the freeway, you still get some boost from tailgaiting and near misses
- avoid crashes by learning the course and slowing down a bit for the corners

I think winning is possible using these tactics, if you can manage not to crash at all.

Answer (score 1):

I always end in second place. Hopefully one of these days I'll win. My advice is that the bugati is waay too fast for the tour. Causing major crashes. The McClaren F1 is the best car to drive overall. Its the best on curves. Try to stay in 3rd place till the last 10 miles of the race...then hawl ass ! Once again always use the McClaren F1.

Answer (score 1):

Take mclaren for the ride. There are few shortcuts to be taken for the lead. On the highway drive in oncoming. Take your drifts better than the others and try not to crash....... :D

Answer (score 0):

Take f1 and drive on oncoming and take shortcuts. I always get at least 20 sec ahead of 2nd place by the time I hit three points road.

Other good cars are ccx and gumpert

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bugatti after learning the course, I've been trying to find lap time records to see how good is 12.26.30?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/312141)

Answer (score -1):

You will finish first if you follow these steps..

1. Use McLaren for 2 times in order to master your drifting skills.
2. After u mastered drifting.. Go to the event with Bugatti Veyron.
3. Avoid crashing ... and always try to be in your own lane , drive the least in oncoming.
4. You will definitely finish 1st  with a lead of at least 23 secs.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to proper grammar? It's really hard to read.